# dynamic Polar plot on normal plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Request a big help on this. I am trying to use a dynamic polar plot on normal plot. I have a random waypoint model. Now, I would like to put a dynamically changing polar plot to reach a few selected users in the random waypoint.

```
function test_Animate(s_mobility,s_input,time_step)

v_t = 0:time_step:s_input.SIMULATION_TIME;


for nodeIndex = 1:s_mobility.NB_NODES
    %Simple interpolation (linear) to get the position, anytime.
    %Remember that "interp1" is the matlab function to use in order to
    %get nodes' position at any continuous time.
    vs_node(nodeIndex).v_x = interp1(s_mobility.VS_NODE(nodeIndex).V_TIME,s_mobility.VS_NODE(nodeIndex).V_POSITION_X,v_t);

    vs_node(nodeIndex).v_y = interp1(s_mobility.VS_NODE(nodeIndex).V_TIME,s_mobility.VS_NODE(nodeIndex).V_POSITION_Y,v_t);


end
fig = figure;

hold on;


   for nodeIndex = 1:s_mobility.NB_NODES




    vh_node_pos(nodeIndex) =   plot(vs_node(nodeIndex).v_x(1),vs_node(nodeIndex).v_y(1),'*','color',[0.3 0.3 1]);



    axis off;

end
title(cat(2,'Simulation time (sec): ',num2str(s_mobility.SIMULATION_TIME)));
xlabel('X (meters)');
ylabel('Y (meters)');
title('Random Waypoint mobility');
ht = text(min(vs_node(1).v_x),max(vs_node(1).v_y),cat(2,'Time (sec) = 0'));
axis([min(vs_node(1).v_x) max(vs_node(1).v_x) min(vs_node(1).v_y) max(vs_node(1).v_y)]);
disp(min(vs_node(1).v_x));
disp(max(vs_node(1).v_x));
disp(min(vs_node(1).v_y));
disp(max(vs_node(1).v_y));

hold off;
for timeIndex = 1:length(v_t);
    t = v_t(timeIndex);
    set(ht,'String',cat(2,'Time (sec) = ',num2str(t,4)));
    for nodeIndex = 1:s_mobility.NB_NODES
              set(vh_node_pos(nodeIndex),'XData',vs_node(nodeIndex).v_x(timeIndex),'YData',vs_node(nodeInd ex).v_y(timeIndex));
        curr_x_pos=vs_node(nodeIndex).v_x(timeIndex);
      %  curr_y_pos=vs_node(nodeIndex).v_y(timeIndex);
        %disp(curr_x_pos);
        %curr_y_pos=vs_node(nodeIndex).v_y(timeIndex);

    end
    drawnow;
  end

  end
```

Now, in this above code, I need to add a polar plot which has directional antenna beam. Please help me out as to how to change the beam position according to user position which we can see on the plot. As in, the beam should encircle the user position dynamically.  The other files regarding this are present code are in the following link. [RANDOM WAYPOINT MOBILITY MODEL](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30939-random-waypoint-mobility-model). Request a big help.

Thanks in advance.